# Find the height of the centre of mass of an annular hemisphere

Tags: calculus, integration

So as stated above I need to find the centre of mass of a annular hemisphere. the outer radius is $R$ and the inner radius is $a$. In a pкevious part to the question I found the volume of the annular hemisphere to be $R\pi(R^2-a^2)$.

Comment: Perhaps it should tell you something that "annular hemisphere" has $11$ Google hits, $3$ of which are for this question. Whatever you mean by that term (perhaps you mean something like [Figure 6 on page 10 here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.4865.pdf)?), it would seem that for $a=0$ its volume should be that of a hemisphere, which is $\frac23\pi R^3$. Could you please explain?

Comment: ok the question as stated is "An object is made of a hemisphere of radius R with a
hole of radius a drilled through its center of symmetry,
as shown in the figure.
(a) Use annular slicing to find the volume of the object.
(b) Its center of mass will be on the vertical axis. Find
the height of the centre of mass.
(c) Calculate its moment of inertia about the y-axis.

Comment: just looked at the link, yea that's what the question's talking about.